# How to add an existing date to a UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I want to add the abbility, to edit an existing action with an attribute date which comes from a datePicker. Than I have to assign the date to a datePicker.

#### Question

How can I assign this date to a datePicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `date` property

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
let date = Date() // current date
picker.date = date
```

If you want animation you can do:

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
let date = Date()
picker.setDate(date, animated: true)
```

A good way to solve such problem is to read documentation of UIDatePicker